# Login via Google email address

Tags: java, android, authentication, google-signin

I'm developing an Android app. 
In this app the user can easily log-in via his or her Google email account without any password or anything to my webservice: the user just needs to select the Google email address from a Spinner and - if the email corresponds to an email in the database in the web service, the web service answers 'OK' and sends back the information related to that email address.

Now, I'm aware this is not a safe system because I could retrieve the same information just asking via POST the server with the email address I want to hack but to develop the app faster I didn't pay much attention to that.

Now, I'm going to release it and I would like to improve the android login system being sure that the user is really authenticated with that email in the android phone but I'd like avoiding all the OAuth system if it is possible.

The user is asked to select the email address from a Spinner and that's all.

Is there a way to do so in a safe way and easy?.

Comment: ask user to input password and save that password in your database? Instead of only matching email, match email and password both

Comment: @PranaliRasal no, I don't want make the login hard. The app is for elderly users and I can't figure out my grandmother saving a password somewhere. Rather she would uninstall the app...

Comment: Use Firebase then..

Comment: @satyan_android how could I use Firebase for such purpose? I have an online database too

Comment: Not an Android dev, but doesnt google provide this kind of authentication for Android apps.  Perhaps if you checkout the likes of Okta, or maybe in this case something like IRMA would be useful.

Comment: @Gavin what is Otka?

Comment: @Soul its a third party identity management/Oauth provider.  much like Auth0.  http://www.okta.com.  If I understand these things as an OAuth provider I think they should provide something similar to what you are looking for.  Though you though might not fit the simplicity for your users you want.

Comment: @Soul IRMA (https://privacybydesign.foundation/en/) might be more suited, they are trying to put control of the information shared into the hands of the users.  I think their email sharing flow might work for you.  Though again it might not have the easy of use you want.  Perhaps you have spotted a gap in the market